# Загрузка файлов на сервер с помощью Synapse

Tags: delphi, загрузка, synapse

Пытаюсь передать файл через библиотеку **[THTTPSendEx](http://arhangelsoft.ru/delphi/advanced-synapse-library-thttpsendex/)**.

Код с **[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471513/how-to-send-a-file-and-other-post-data-with-synapse)**:

```
var
 HTTP:THTTPSendEx;
 Data:TMultipartFormDataStream;
 sHTML:string; //Recived HTML code from web
begin
 HTTP:=THTTPSEndEx.Create;
 Data:=TMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
 try
  Data.AddFile('myFile','Path to the local file(No UNC paths)');
  Data.DataEnd;
  if HTTP.Post('URL HERE',Data,sHTML) then
  begin
  //Connection established
  //Check HTTP response
  if HTTP.IsSuccessfull then  //HTTP returns "200 OK" code.
  begin
    ShowMessage('File successfully posted to the server.');
  end;
  end else
  begin
   ShowMessage('Can not establish a connection to the server...'+#13+'Network is not avaliable or server socket does not exist.');
  end;
 finally
   FreeAndNil(HTTP);
   FreeAndNil(Data);
 end;
end;
```

Мой код:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 HTTP:THTTPSendEx;
 Data:TMultipartFormDataStream;
 sHTML:string; //Recived HTML code from web
begin
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
begin
 HTTP:=THTTPSEndEx.Create;
 Data:=TMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
 try
  Data.AddFile('myFile', OpenDialog1.FileName);
  Data.DataEnd;
  if HTTP.Post('http://kaon.rghost.ru/files',Data,sHTML) then
  begin
  //Connection established
  //Check HTTP response
  if HTTP.IsSuccessfull then  //HTTP returns "200 OK" code.
  begin
    ShowMessage('File successfully posted to the server.');
  end;
  end else
  begin
   ShowMessage('Can not establish a connection to the server...'+#13+'Network is not avaliable or server socket does not exist.');
  end;
 finally
   FreeAndNil(HTTP);
   FreeAndNil(Data);
 end;
end;
end;
```

Но ничего не выводит. Подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: @Muhammad97, Оформляйте ответы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться. Публикуйте полное условие, а не ссылку на другой форум.

Comment: @Muhammad97 Что конкретно работает не так, как вы ожидаете?

Comment: Ожидаю File successfully posted to the server

Comment: @Muhammad97 А посмотреть что у вас в `sHTML` вернулось не пробовали? Что вы вообще пробовали? Или вы ждете, что кто-то сделает вашу задачу за вас?

Comment: Спасибо, не додумался, возвращает:
Ошибку 500 your request could not be processed at the moment, because of an error on the server

Comment: @Muhammad97 пожалуйста